# How to optimize the code to avoid a time limit error

Tags: c, arrays, file, time-limiting

I'm creating a prog for my exam. The code works properly but i got Time Limit error. How I can write this code bettere to avoid this error?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
  int a, sum;

   float b, i;
   i=0;
   sum=0;
   FILE *file1;
   file1=fopen("input.txt","w");
   do{
    fscanf(file1, "%d", &a);
    if(a!=0){
     sum=sum+a;
     i++;
    }
   } while(a!=0);
   fclose(file1);
   b=(sum/i);
   printf("%f", b);
   FILE *file2;
   file2=fopen("output.txt","w");
   fprintf(file2, "%f", b);
   fclose(file2);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does “time limit error” mean? I think you put the code into a system checking its complexity. Moreover, you need to explain what the problem is and what you wish to get as a result.

Comment: `float i` and `i=0`, why?

Comment: While the compiler don't really care about spaces and indentation, it's important for us humans that try to read and understand the code. Please edit your question and its code to have consistent indentation. An empty line or two to add "paragraphs" in the code would also be nice.

Comment: *The code works properly...*  The posted code certainly does not "work properly".  `file1=fopen("input.txt","w");` opens the `input.txt` file for **writing** - after truncating it to zero bytes.  Assuming the code you must have *meant* to post opened `input.txt` in read mode, what other differences from that code exist?

Comment: could you provide a complete, minimal, reproducible example? what does input and output contain?

Comment: If the file is empty or does not start with a digit (and was opened properly) you will end up with an unitialized `a` and unless it is zero just by pure accident, you will loop forever

Answer (score 2):

This code is a potential problem:

```
   do{
    fscanf(file1, "%d", &a);
    if(a!=0){
     sum=sum+a;
     i++;
    }
   } while(a!=0);
```

You don't check the return value from `fscanf()`, so when you hit the end of the input file, if the last value you read is non-zero, your code will go into an infinite loop.

A better solution:

```
   do{
    int numScanned = fscanf(file1, "%d", &a);

    // break loop if fscanf() fails for any reason
    if ( numScanned != 1 ) break;

    if(a!=0){
     sum=sum+a;
     i++;
    }
   } while(a!=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove  fscanf(file1, "%d", &a); from do while there is no use of it because you are opening input.txt file in "w" mode so it will truncate and considered as new empty file. so, it don't have any content inside it. this way time complexity will be reduced.

Comment: This does not really provide a solution or answer the question, does it? If it is only intented to point in the right direction, then it should be a comment. If you don't have enough reputation to write a comment, that is not an excuse to write it as an answer instead. Please don't do this.